# WordPress rewrite rule depend on meta values not ids

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type and i'm using the rewrite rule to change the URL from

```
mysite.com/collection?brand1=365&brand2=412
```

to

```
mysite.com/collection/compare/365-412
```

But I want to depend on meta value for more nice SEO url and user friendly

The meta will be the "model"of post

```
mysite.com/collection/compare/bmw-vs-ibm
```

How can I do that by WordPress rewrite rule function?

(not by .htaccess rewrite or URL rewriting with PHP)

Comment: How are you doing the first transformation from ?brand=365&brand2=412 to the /compare/365-412 form? I'd guess you'll need to hook that somewhere but I can't remember how that is done (since add_rewrite_rule specifies the opposite transformation I think?). There doesn't appear to be anywhere to add logic to or hook the write rule itself.

Comment: @Rup I doing it bt this code  add_rewrite_rule('collection/([^/]+)-vs-([^/]+)/?$',
   'index.php?post_type=collection&brand1=$matches[1]&brand2=$matches[2]',
   'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('collection/([^/]+)-vs-([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$',
   'index.php?post_type=collection&brand1=$matches[1]&&brand2=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
   'top');

Comment: add_filter( 'query_vars', 'pmg_rewrite_add_var' );
function pmg_rewrite_add_var( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'brand1';
    $vars[] = 'brand2';
    return $vars;
}

Comment: OK, thanks. I meant how are you generating the `mysite.com/collection/compare/365-412` form? Is WordPress doing that automatically, i.e. you'd need to find what's doing that and change it? Or are you constructing that form somewhere?

Comment: If the problem is just parsing `brand1=bmw` into `brand1=365` then that should be fairly straightforward in the code that handles the brand1 and brand2 query paramaters: if the value is a number then it's an ID, else it's a term slug that needs looking up.

Comment: Hi @Rup, it shows s compare between two brands and it displays the features depend on the post ID . I need to make the url contains the meta values instead of IDs by rewrite rules

Comment: OK, but is the problem generating an URL with 'bmw', or processing the URL with 'bmw', or both? You're going to have to write some code for one if not both of these I'd think.

Comment: @Mohamedahmed Do I understand your questino right that you want a URL `/bmw-vs-ibm` where `bmw` and `ibm` are values from a post meta field `model`, and you want to get the two posts that have those values set in the `model` post meta field?

Comment: @mozboz, exactly that I need. and display features depend on the post meta values instead of the post IDs

Comment: Then I think this is how do you write a URL like: `mysite.com/collection?brand1meta=ibm&brand2meta=bmw`. If you can do that, the URL rewrite part is easy. As Rup says, this will take some code to intercept somewhere to change from a meta ID to a post ID

Comment: So I need the help!